# Get selected value from dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist which shows a list of countries from my database

```
public void ShowCountries()
    {
        OdbcConnection conn;
        conn = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jConnString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT iso,printable_name FROM country";

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);


        try
        {
            //ddlCountry.DataSourceID = "country";
            ddlCountry.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "printable_name";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "iso";
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Check.Text = "3" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            ddlCountry.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

in the aspx file this is the way how I call this databounded list

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" 
DataTextField="printable_name" 
DataValueField="iso">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

It shows the list but if I want to select an option other then the first one it always inserts the value of the first option en never the selected one, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: how do you select an option in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like the data source is being (re-)bound to the control before you are accessing the selected value, thus the selected value is always the first value in the datasource.

Where and when does `ShowCountries` get called? At a guess, I'd say you're missing a check for `IsPostback` in `Page_Load`

```
if (!IsPostback) {
    // bind the datasource here, when the page initially loads
    ShowCountries();
}
```

Also, I don't think you want to call `Dispose()` on `ddlCountry` in the `finally` block.